# How replace img based on window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I am trying to replace `img src` based on window size. This is not a `background-image`. For mobile size my image needs to be different color/image then larger screens. It is easy to change size of image with css but I think I need to use Jquery to replace image src but cant figure it out yet. Any pointers?

here is my html

```
<a href="" class="logo">
   <img id="brand" src="assets/img/image.png" alt="Image">
</a>
```

here is my js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var windowSize = $( window ).width();
    if (windowSize  < 400 ) { $('#brand').attr('src', 'assets/img/logo-2.png')};

});
```

ALL this seems to do is change on load img src not change on window size or resize window.

--edit -- form humbolight

```
$(function(){
  var $window = $(window);
  var toggleImage = function toggleImage($el, src){
    $el.attr('src',src);
  };

  $window.on('resize',function(){
    if ($window.width() < 385){
      //mobile
      toggleImage($('#brand'),'assets/img/image.png');
    } else {
      //landscape tablet/desktop
      toggleImage($('#brand'),'assets/img/logo-2.png');
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Remove the quotes from around `windowSize`. It's a variable so you can access it as such by simply using `if(windowSize < 400) { ... }`

Comment: If you look for a dynamic way to control the page on resize events, look into [$(window).resize()](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are attempting to accomplish would require listening to the resize event on the window element and changing the src based on the changing width (preloading images wouldn't hurt):

```js
$(function(){

  var $window = $(window);
  
  var toggleImage = function toggleImage($el, src){
    $el.attr('src',src);
  };
  
  $window.on('resize',function(){
    if ($window.width() < 768){
      //mobile
      toggleImage($('#two_size_img'),'img@1x.png');
    } else {
      //landscape tablet/desktop
      toggleImage($('#two_size_img'),'img@2x.png');
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="two_size_img" src="img@1x.png" />
```

To accomplish the same end, I would favor toggling a background-image, handled entirely with CSS, or similarly, rendering both elements (one img per image wanted) and showing/hiding the desired image -- again, entirely with CSS.

Comment: Please mark answer as correct if it solved your issue, thanks!